# Box: Getting image url for sharing

Tags: ios, box-api, boxapiv2

Currently **sharedLink** url for a file is of html type. 
How can I directly get image url to share instead of getting url of html type.

Currently I'm getting below url as sharedLink for an image, which is of html type

https://app.box.com/s/53auzqp2sdx2ki9dl8kw

How can I directly get url with image extension as below, which I got by inspecting above link in browser.

https://app.box.com/representation/file_version_20217702945/image_2048_jpg/1.jpg?shared_name=53auzqp2sdx2ki9dl8kw

Comment: only one line of description not enough my friend please put some code and how you url looks in response. try to find also at box developer support forums. this is not a well explain question

Comment: Also, you might be looking to get the thumbnail... search the documentation for thumbnails, and you'll find some help doing that

Comment: @niks have you get any solution? I am getting same issue!1

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya this feature is known as direct link in box. The problem is it's only available for paid users.